Finding the area of an ellipse which is the intersection of $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=1+2x$.
I'm not sure of the names of different parts of an ellipse but here goes.
I'm trying to Find the area of an ellipse which is the intersection of $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=1+2x$. The area is given by $\pi ab$ where $b$ and $a$ are half the length of the major and minor axis respectively.
From both equations we have $1+2x=x^2+y^2\iff (x-1)^2+y^2=2$. The largest value of $z$ with this constraint is $z(1+\sqrt{2})$ and least $z(1-\sqrt{2})$. Thus follows that the vertices of the major axis are $(1+\sqrt{2},0,3+2\sqrt{2})$ and $(1-\sqrt{2},0,3-2\sqrt{2})$. Thus the length of the major axis is $||(2\sqrt{2},0,4\sqrt{2})||=\sqrt{40}$ which follows $b=\sqrt{10}$.
I don't know how to obtain the vertices of the minor axis. I guessed that the z components of the vertices of the minor axis is half the length of $z(1+\sqrt{2})$ and $z(1-\sqrt{2})$ but it is wrong.

Hint: you've got the major axis. The midpoint of the major axis is also the midpoint of the minor axis (ie the centre of the ellipse).

Another solution comes from thinking of the projection of the ellipse onto the $xy$-plane. I realize that this is not the approach you were expected to take, but this might be useful to you in the future.
Eliminating the variable $z$, we find the equation $x^2+y^2=1+2x$, so the projection is the circle
$$(x-1)^2+y^2=2,$$
whose area is $2\pi$. Now, the ellipse lies in the tilted plane $2x-z+1=0$, whose unit normal vector is $\vec n=\frac1{\sqrt5}(2,0,-1)$. Thus, if $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec n$ and $\vec k=(0,0,1)$, we have $|\cos\theta| = |\vec n\cdot \vec k| = \frac1{\sqrt5}$. As this picture shows,

this means that the area of the ellipse in the tilted plane is $\frac1{|\cos\theta|} = \sqrt5$ times the area of the projection, and thus the area of the ellipse is $2\sqrt 5\pi$.

Can you pls elaborate your last paragraph??

Changing coordinates in the plane $z=1+2x$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+X\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+Y\begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt5\\0\\2/\sqrt5\end{pmatrix},$$
the equation of the ellipse becomes
$$\frac{X^2}2+\frac{(Y-\sqrt5)^2}{10}=1$$
hence
$$a=\sqrt2\text{ and }b=\sqrt{10}.$$

can you pls elaborate..  how did you change coordinates and how did matrices come into play??

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad The "matrices" are nothing but points and vectors in $\Bbb R^3$. I parametrized points in the plane $P: z=1+2x$ under the form $A+Xu+Yv$ where $A\in P$ and $(u,v)$ is an orthonormal basis of $\vec P$.

The ellipse can be written in parametric form as:
$$x = 1 + \sqrt{2}\cos t$$
$$y = \sqrt{2} \sin t$$
$$z = 3 + 2\sqrt{2}\cos t$$
Where $x$ and $y$ form the $xy$-plane circle given by $(x-1)^2+y^2=2$, and then $z$ is chosen to satisfy $z = 1 + 2x$.
The center of the ellipse is the average value of $(x, y, z)$ over $t \in [0, 2\pi)$, which is just $(1, 0, 3)$.  The distance $d$ between a point on the ellipse and the center is given by:
$$d^2 = (x - 1)^2 + (y - 0)^2 + (z - 3)^2$$
$$d^2 = (\sqrt{2}\cos t)^2 + (\sqrt{2} \sin t)^2 + (2\sqrt{2}\cos t)^2$$
$$d^2 = 2\cos^2 t + 2\sin^2 t + 8\cos^2 t$$
$$d^2 = 2 + 8\left(\frac{\cos(2t) + 1}{2}\right)$$
$$d^2 = 6 + 4\cos(2t)$$
$$d = \sqrt{6 + 4\cos(2t)}$$
This distance is minimized when $\cos(2t) = -1$ (so $d = \sqrt{2}$), and maximized when $\cos(2t) = +1$ (so $d = \sqrt{10}$).  Thus, the ellipse has half-axis lengths $a = \sqrt{10}$ and $b = \sqrt{2}$.
The area of the ellipse is $\pi ab = \pi \sqrt{10} \sqrt{2} = \pi \sqrt{20} = \boxed{2\pi\sqrt{5}}$.
